# WS_EX_NOACTIVATE style window on Mac

Tags: macos

Looking for a way to set an application on Mac to still receive mouse input but stay in the background, similar to the Windows Extended Style WS_EX_NOACTIVATE.

Currently doing this in AutoHotKey on Windows with the code WinSet, ExStyle, +0x08000000L, A

Need a way to set a window to this style on Mac, and can't seem to find any information on it. Can't find any window style that behaves like this, and a way to make a running application change window styles.